# Display Country Entity inside the Index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, razor, ef-code-first

I have an entity called Fixture, and basically I want to display some fixtures on the page.

My Model is as follows :-

```
    public class Fixture
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FixtureId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Fixture Date")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? FixtureDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime? FixtureTime { get; set; }

    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }

    public int CountryIdA { get; set; }
    public int CountryIdB { get; set; }

    public int? ScoreA { get; set; }
    public int? ScoreB { get; set; }

    public Round Round { get; set; }
    public int? RoundId { get; set; }

    public List<Scorer> Scorers { get; set; }
}
```

and my ViewModel is as follows :-

```
    public class FixtureViewModel
{
    public Fixture Fixture { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Fixture> FixtureList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<GroupCountry> GroupCountryList { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Group> GroupList { get; set; }

    public string CountryNameA { get; set; }
    public string CountryNameB { get; set; }
}
```

and I am displaying them in this index page :-

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Date")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Country A")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Country A")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Score A")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Score B")
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayName("Round")
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (Fixture item in Model.FixtureList)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FixtureDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryIdA)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryIdB)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScoreA)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ScoreB)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Round.RoundName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = item.FixtureId}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new {id = item.FixtureId}) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = item.FixtureId})
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Now in the index page, I wish to display something like this :-

```
            <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryIdA.Country.CountryName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CountryIdB.Country.CountryName)
        </td>
```

How can I achieve that?

I added a navigation item Country in the Model, however I still cannot display the correct CountryName.

Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `CountryIdA` and `CountryIdB` are just Integers. If you are trying to say...

> Find a fixture with CountryIdA/B, then get it's Country, and then CountryName

then this is not appropriate to put in a view. Your view should not handle any data access, that is the job of your controller/model. I would suggest adding two Country properties to your view model, one for IdA and one for IdB. Then you can populate these in your controller action and have access to them in your view.

Your controller might look something like...

ViewModel.CountryA = Countries.Where(x => x.CountryID = ViewModel.CountryIdA)

Comment: Hi Elliot, when I tried to do that, since I am using code first, it added 2 new fields in the database, Country_CountryIdA, and Country_CountryIdB.  I do not wish to have this in the db.  Is that possible?

Comment: Add them to your View Model, not your Table Model. That is the purpose of the View Model.

Comment: I have already added them in my ViewModel, however I have no idea on how to populate them.  However I have no idea on how to populate them.  I know I have to iterate through the list in the Index Controller Action, but I do not know how to populate them and display them in the view

Comment: Well you must have access to your repository of countries. And you already have Country IdA and IdB right? Then all you need to do in your controller (as ive shown above) is call your repository WHERE countryid equals IdA or IdB.

Comment: Yes I understand what you mean, however since I have a list of Fixtures coming from the ViewModel :-             viewModel.FixtureList = unitOfWork.FixturesRepository.Get(orderBy: d=> d.OrderBy(x=>x.FixtureDate).ThenBy(x=>x.CountryIdA), includeProperties: "Round");
, how can I "attach" ViewModel.CountryA and ViewModel.CountryB to this list?

Comment: Ok I solved it.  Created a new ViewModel, with Fixture and CountryNameA and CountryNameB, and using that list instead of the FixtureList

Comment: It seems to me like your Fixture class should have two navigation properties, one for each country. Then your ViewModel wouldn't need any properties for CountryName or anything. You could just call Fixture.CountryA.Name

Comment: If I create 2 navigation properties, I am getting a field in the database, Country_CountryIdA and Country_CountryIdB

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Fixture in your model by creating a partial class Fixture in the same namespace, create two custom properties CountryIdA/B that does a lookup for the currect IDs.